# Python - Trying to make a reboot button for Cardapio

Tags: python

I'm trying to turn one of the buttons at the bottom of the Cardapio window into a reboot button. I know the area that needs to be edited but don't know what do put that will make it act like a reboot button - like if you entered "gnome-session-quit --reboot" from a command line. The other two act like logout and shutdown buttons and act like they should.

here's the area of code -

```
_('Reboot'),
            _('Reboot the System'),
            'system-restart',
                            self.de.??????????????????????,
            self._view.RIGHT_SESSION_PANE,
        ],
        [
            _('Log Out'),
            _('Log out of this session to log in as a different user'),
            'system-log-out',
            self.de.save_session,
            self._view.RIGHT_SESSION_PANE,
        ],

        [
            _('Shut Down'),
            _('Shut down the system'),
            'system-shutdown',
            self.de.shutdown,
            self._view.RIGHT_SESSION_PANE,
```

Comment: Hm.  What is `Cardapio`? My google does not returns something related to python.

Comment: drop down menu app for Linux/Ubuntu

Comment: it's controlled by file cardapio.py

Answer (score 0):

There is a DesktopEnvironment.py file that lays out all of the self.de.xxx commands

I added 
self.reboot      = 'gnome-session-quit --reboot'
to this file

then the cardapio.py needed to point to it

_('Reboot'),
                _('Reboot the System'),
                'system-reboot',
                                self.de.reboot
                self._view.RIGHT_SESSION_PANE,

There you go. Working reboot button